# Assign a bash associative array in awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

My question is, is it possible to assign a bash variable within an awk script.

i.e
Assuming following is a shell script I have written,

```
declare -A sample_associative_array
awk -F'=' '{$sample_associative_array[$2]=$1}'  /tmp/sample.txt
```

given /tmp/sample.txt has:

```
abc=0
def=1
```

I tried

```
echo $sample_associative_array[0]
```

and it doesnt work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. Awk and Bash use totally different scopes of variables, and allowing one to use the variables declared in another one would be a great violation of process sovereignty.

What you're trying to do can be very simply done with Bash via using parameter expansion with removal of the prefix/suffix, e.g. `${parameter#word}` and `${parameter%word}`. Consult the Bash manual for more information.

Also, array references in Bash use other syntax : `${sample_associative_array[0]}` is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, regarding echo ${sample_array[0]}, I knew that but somehow missed it out. Can you tell me what I need to search for regarding this parameter expansion? It would be great if you could provide an example. Cheers!

Comment: Okay, Got it! Thanks a lot for the answer! For those who are looking for this kind of match, here is a nice article: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-parameter-expansion

Comment: @Unsung: Search `man bash` for `Arrays`: *Any element of an array may be referenced using ${name[subscript]}.*

Answer (score 9):

Not quite the same thing, but you can have `awk` output strings that can be used by the `bash` built-in command `declare` to populate an associative array. I'm not entirely sure why you would want to do this, though.

```sh
$ declare $( awk -F'=' '{print "aa["$2"]="$1}' sample.txt )
$ echo ${aa[0]}
abc
$ echo ${aa[1]}
def
```

Comment: I wanted to read a file and get an associative array out of it. And from my experience, I felt awk would be a natural candidate for this. Hence I went that way. But now, I'm going for the usual parameter expansion option provided by bash. I'm doing a prefix and suffix match on the data and populating my associative array. Thanks for the alternative method though. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

No.  A child process cannot assign to a variable in the parent, you would have this issue regardless of the language.  `awk` cannot even directly *read* a `bash` associative array either, since you cannot export an array from bash (or any other shell that I know of).

You will always get these kinds of problems when trying to mix languages.  General tip is to write the whole lot in either `bash` or `awk`, both are quite powerful.

Comment: Well explained! Looking at this in terms of process makes it a bit clearer.